# Apply function converting data frame to character when error returned from API

Tags: r, function, coercion

I have written a function to query the CMS National Plan and Provider Enumeration System (NPPES) API.

I wish to pass in a data frame of NPI values and return their addresses.

Some of the NPI values are no longer valid and I have tried to build some error handling for these scenarios.

My error handling `if else` statement specifies to use a data frame of dimensions 1 row by 6 columns and I have inserted the errored NPI value into row 1 column 1.

When I use the apply function against my data frame I get a list [1x6] for all the successful API calls but the errored values are just a single character vector.

I have tried to debug this issue but I can't figure out where the conversion from data frame to character is happening. I would be very grateful if anyone could help me please.

Here is a dataframe of values I wish to query:

```
install.packages("pacman")
library(pacman)

pacman::p_load(tidyverse,data.table,httr,jsonlite)

values <- c(1598727430,
            1083632731,
            1710983663) # LAST VALUE PRODUCES THE ERROR CASE

npi_values <- data.frame(values)
```

here is the URL for the API:

```
path <- "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?"
```

My function:

```
# CREATE A FUNCTION TO PULL NPI INFORMATION FROM THE NPI REGISTRY
getNPI <- function(object) {
  request <- httr::GET(
    url = path,
    query = list(
      version = "2.0",
      number = object
    )
  )
  Sys.sleep(0.25)
  
  warn_for_status(request)

  npi_details <- content(request,
    as = "text",
    encoding = "UTF-8"
  ) %>%
    fromJSON(.,
      flatten = TRUE
    ) %>%
    data.frame()
  # IF THE API THROWS BACK A RESULT WHERE THE COLUMN NAMES CONTAIN 'ERROR'
  # THEN ASSIGN ALL THE ROW VALUES TO NA AND ADD THE NPI VALUE TO THE FIRST
  # COLUMN
  if (any(grepl("ERROR", toupper(colnames(npi_details))))) {
    
    npi_details <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,ncol = 6,nrow = 1)) %>% 
      dplyr::rename(`NPI NUMBER` = V1,
             `CMS REF ADDRESS 1` = V2,
             `CMS REF ADDRESS 2` = V3,
             `CMS REF CITY` = V4,
             `CMS REF STATE` = V5,
             `CMS REF ZIP` = V6)
    
    npi_details[1,1] <- object
    
    # ELSE IF THE DATA FRAME DOES NOT CONTAIN 'ERROR' THEN RUN THIS CHUNK
  } else {
    select(npi_details, contains(c("addresses", "number"))) %>%
      unnest(c(contains("address"))) %>%
      filter(address_purpose == "MAILING") %>%
      rename_all(.funs = toupper) %>%
      select(
        `NPI NUMBER` = RESULTS.NUMBER,
        -COUNTRY_CODE,
        -COUNTRY_NAME,
        -ADDRESS_PURPOSE,
        -ADDRESS_TYPE,
        `CMS REF ADDRESS 1` = ADDRESS_1,
        `CMS REF ADDRESS 2` = ADDRESS_2,
        `CMS REF CITY` = CITY,
        `CMS REF STATE` = STATE,
        `CMS REF ZIP` = POSTAL_CODE
      )
  }
}
```

I then apply this function against the data frame of NPI values above:

```
out <- apply(npi_values, 1, getNPI)
```

When I apply this to my real dataset you can see below that the error case is converted to a character even though I specify a data frame of size 1 row by 6 columns

**Based on feedback from @akrun I have modified my apply statement to include wrapping the getNPI function in a list, see below:**

```
out <- apply(npi_values, 1, function(x) list(getNPI(x)))
```

The structure of `out` now looks as follows:

```
str(out)
List of 3
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : tibble [1 × 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. ..$ NPI NUMBER       : int 1598727430
  .. ..$ CMS REF ADDRESS 1: chr "PO BOX 17567"
  .. ..$ CMS REF ADDRESS 2: chr ""
  .. ..$ CMS REF CITY     : chr "PENSACOLA"
  .. ..$ CMS REF STATE    : chr "FL"
  .. ..$ CMS REF ZIP      : chr "325227567"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : tibble [1 × 6] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. ..$ NPI NUMBER       : int 1083632731
  .. ..$ CMS REF ADDRESS 1: chr "PO BOX 17326"
  .. ..$ CMS REF ADDRESS 2: chr ""
  .. ..$ CMS REF CITY     : chr "DENVER"
  .. ..$ CMS REF STATE    : chr "CO"
  .. ..$ CMS REF ZIP      : chr "802170326"
 $ :List of 1
  ..$ : Named num 1.71e+09
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "values"
```

When I try to collapse these lists into data frame of 3 rows by 6 columns, the last case (errored case) drops into a 7th column which is not desired. I wish to have the value from the 3 case stored in the first column with remaining values filled with NA.

Desired outcome:

```
`NPI NUMBER` <- c(1598727430,1083632731,1710983663)
`CMS REF ADDRESS 1` <- c("PO BOX 17567","PO BOX 17326",NA)
`CMS REF ADDRESS 2` <- c("","",NA)
`CMS REF CITY` <- c("PENSACOLA","DENVER",NA)
`CMS REF STATE` <- c("FL","CO",NA)
`CMS REF ZIP` <- c("325227567","802170326",NA)
desired <- data.frame(`NPI NUMBER`,`CMS REF ADDRESS 1`,`CMS REF ADDRESS 2`,`CMS REF CITY`,`CMS REF STATE`,`CMS REF ZIP`)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with `tryCatch`

Comment: Hi akrun, yes I have but not successfully. I abandoned that approach as the API returns an actual data frame and not an official 'error' I believe.

Comment: Try by wrapping in a `list` i.e. `apply(npi_values, 1, function(x) list(getNPI(x)))`   The example showed didn't have any issue for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to return the value of npi_details within the `if` part of the if else statement in order to keep the work around tibble I created for the errored cases!

```
# CREATE A FUNCTION TO PULL NPI INFORMATION FROM THE NPI REGISTRY
getNPI <- function(object) {
  request <- httr::GET(
    url = path,
    query = list(
      version = "2.0",
      number = object
    )
  )
  Sys.sleep(0.25)

  warn_for_status(request)

  npi_details <- content(request,
    as = "text",
    encoding = "UTF-8"
  ) %>%
    fromJSON(.,
      flatten = TRUE
    ) %>%
    data.frame()
  # IF THE API THROWS BACK A RESULT WHERE THE COLUMN NAMES CONTAIN 'ERROR'
  # THEN ASSIGN ALL THE ROW VALUES TO NA AND ADD THE NPI VALUE TO THE FIRST
  # COLUMN
  if (any(grepl("ERROR", toupper(colnames(npi_details))))) {
    npi_details <- as.data.frame(matrix("error", ncol = 6, nrow = 1), stringsAsFactors = FALSE) %>%
      dplyr::rename(
        `NPI NUMBER` = V1,
        `CMS REF ADDRESS 1` = V2,
        `CMS REF ADDRESS 2` = V3,
        `CMS REF CITY` = V4,
        `CMS REF STATE` = V5,
        `CMS REF ZIP` = V6
      ) %>% as_tibble()
    
    npi_details[1,1] <- as.character(object)
    return(npi_details)

    # ELSE IF THE DATA FRAME DOES NOT CONTAIN 'ERROR' THEN RUN THIS CHUNK
  } else {
    select(npi_details, contains(c("addresses", "number"))) %>%
      unnest(c(contains("address"))) %>%
      filter(address_purpose == "MAILING") %>%
      rename_all(.funs = toupper) %>%
      select(
        `NPI NUMBER` = RESULTS.NUMBER,
        -COUNTRY_CODE,
        -COUNTRY_NAME,
        -ADDRESS_PURPOSE,
        -ADDRESS_TYPE,
        `CMS REF ADDRESS 1` = ADDRESS_1,
        `CMS REF ADDRESS 2` = ADDRESS_2,
        `CMS REF CITY` = CITY,
        `CMS REF STATE` = STATE,
        `CMS REF ZIP` = POSTAL_CODE
      ) %>% 
      mutate(`NPI NUMBER` = as.character(`NPI NUMBER`))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply()` converts its provided object to a matrix, in which all values must be of the same type. The most general type is character, therefore it gets converted to character and your function is applied to this character matrix.

see `?apply()`:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via as.array.